# PHP: Merging arrays with the same title

Tags: php, arrays

I have some php arrays from a loop, all of them bearing the same name. Now I want to merge them, but it seems not to work...

Here's my loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql1)){
    $startzeit=strtotime($row[2]);
    $endzeit=strtotime($row[3]);
    $startzeit_format = date("Y-m-d",$startzeit);
    $endzeit_format = date("Y-m-d",$endzeit);
    $datearray[] = createDateRangeArray($startzeit_format,$endzeit_format);
    }
```

This should be the merging code:

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($datearray); $i++)
    {
    $datesarray = array_merge($datearray[$i]);
    }
```

Anyway, the manual merge works fine:

```
$datesarray = array_merge( $datearray[0], $datearray[1], $datearray[2], $datearray[3]);
```

This one leads to the desired output. However I'd like to automatize it, as the single arrays come from a database and I won't add a $datearray[4], $datearray[5] and so on, everytime there is a new entry in the mySQL..

The result of `print_r($datearray)`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 2014-03-08 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [0] => 2013-09-15 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => 2013-09-21 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => 2013-10-03 
                   [1] => 2013-10-04 
                   [2] => 2013-10-05 
                   [3] => 2013-10-06 )
      )
```

Comment: "all of them bearing the same name", what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might be looking for is to flatten the array:

```
$datesarray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $datearray);
```

It's identical to how you were manually merging together the array items.

See also: [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)

You could also do this inside the loop with a simple loop:

```
$datesarray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($sql1)) {
    // ...
    foreach (createDateRangeArray($startzeit_format,$endzeit_format) as $item) {
        $datesarray[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: and instantiate the `$datesarray = array();` outside the MySQL while loop so it's kept between all rows.

Comment: @Prix Yeah, though technically that's not a hard requirement; it's PHP after all :)

Comment: Too bad I can't double vote :P both suggestions should work just fine for the OP needs, while the later is better IMHO.

Comment: @StanD'Ard Thanks; personally I feel the second is better because it doesn't need an intermediate array, but that's an opinion :)

Comment: @StanD'Ard you should consider using the 2nd option it will probably be slight more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You are merging a single array to nothing.

```
$newArray = array_merge($array, $array)
```

Merges those two arrays but you are doing

```
$array = array_merge($datearray[$i]);
```

In affect, you are creating an array from one key of an array.